# No manda SMS android studio

Tags: android

estoy intentando hacer pruebas de envio de SMS pero no manda nada.

> **Permisos**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Menu_AgroMovil.this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Menu_AgroMovil.this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Menu_AgroMovil.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
   } else {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Menu_AgroMovil.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
   }
}else {
   //...
}
```

> **Boton de enviar**

```
String number = "12121"; //claro un numero coherente. 
String sms = "Mensaje a enviar ...";

try {
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,sms,null,null);
   Toast.makeText(Menu_AgroMovil.this,"SMS enviado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (Exception e){
   Toast.makeText(Menu_AgroMovil.this,"Error al enviar SMS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: El código se ve bien a primera vista. Te aseguraste que tienes saldo para enviar SMS y que no rechazaste el privilegio en alguno de tus pruebas marcando "no preguntar más"? Podrías tirar un poco de `Log.d()` a donde compruebas los "permissions"

Comment: añadiste     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
 en tu manifest?

Answer (score 1):

**A. Permisos en el manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

**B. Luego puedes enviarlo de dos formas:**

***1. Con SmsManager***

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("elNumero", null, "mensaje sms", null, null);
```

***2. Con Pending Intent***

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("cuerpo_sms", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**Nota:** Si no funciona por favor muestra el mensaje de error que te está dando.

Comment: si manda el mensaje pero me dice **error al enviar** en la app de mensajes de android

Comment: ¿Pero da la causa del error? ¿Puedes mostrar lo que dice en el logcat, editando tu pregunta? ¿Tienes saldo suficiente para enviar el SMS?